# Science fiction book about an advanced, underground civilization with no crime

Tags: story-identification, books

The book talks about an underground civilization, which is highly advanced, very peaceful, very sincere where no crime is present.

Moral values and rules were different and soon complications started to happen with the Earth visitors. This civilization was discovered by mistake, by either a geological tour, or some kind of trip where they stumble through a cave opening then enter it.

It is highly enjoyable and I was very intrigued by it. I do recall that the author was a doctor, or physician but then again I may be wrong, it’s been more than 20 years since I've read it.

Comment: @LogicDictates, why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - _[A Crystal Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Crystal_Age)_ matches some of the points raised in the question, but having read the beginning of it at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/7401/7401-h/7401-h.htm), it doesn't appear to be set underground, which seems like a big strike against the probability of it being the right answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short story I read - Outsiders enter hedonistic utopian society where citizens live forever by transferring bodies, havoc ensues](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107519/short-story-i-read-outsiders-enter-hedonistic-utopian-society-where-citizens-l)

Comment: @Laurel I can’t see a confirmed answer from the OP here. There’s the other account which may or may not be the OP but that’s it unless I’m missing something.

Answer (score 19):

This sounds like the novel [Abduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abduction_(novel)) by Robin Cook from 2000.

Points that match:

> underground civilization, which is highly advanced, very peaceful, very sincere where no crime is present.

Check.  "They discover a technologically advanced world of genetically engineered, physically near-perfect humans living comfortably in an enclosed city within the Mohorovičić discontinuity. "

> Moral values and rules were different and soon complications started to happen with the Earth visitors.

Check. Sexual mores are different which causes a major complication with the surface visitors.

> This civilization was discovered by mistake, by either a geological tour, or some kind of trip where they stumble through a cave opening then enter it.

Check. A team of researchers in a remote region of the Atlantic become trapped inside an ancient undersea volcano when their submersible is inexplicably drawn in.

> It is highly enjoyable and I was very intrigued by it. I do recall that the author was a doctor, or physician but then again I may be wrong,

Check. Robin Cook was a physician by training and has written several dozen medical thrillers.

> it’s been more than 20 years since I've read it.

Check. Published in 2000 so just over 20 years ago.

Comment: Thank you @beichst !
Yes, it is abduction by Robin Cook!
I appreciate the help!

Comment: I’ve tried, then tried some more to find the book using google searches and gave up! Now thanks to your answer, the search saga is over!

Comment: @Bledi Hi, welcome to SF&F.  If you are the original poster of the question, you should [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can accept the answer.  If you are not the OP, please don't post "thank-you" answers; when you've earned some reputation you'll be able to leave comments instead.